# Combining same objects in json array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, sorting

I have this array:

```
[{ "id": 1, "myId": "100", "name": "amey" }, { "id": 2, "myId": "100", "name": "anuj" }, { "id": 3, "myId": "101", "name": "suraj" }, { "id": 4, "myId": "101", "name": "suraj h" }]
```

I want output like this:

```
[{ "id": 1, "myId": "100", "name": ["amey", "anuj"] }, { "id": 3, "myId": "101", "name": ["suraj", "suraj h] }]
```

How can I do this using javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
  //And loop again for duplicate data
  for (var j = i + 1; j < myarray.length; j++) {
    if (
      myarray[i].VENDOR_ID == myarray[j].VENDOR_ID &&
      myarray[i].ORDER_ID === myarray[j].ORDER_ID
    ) {
      var tmp = myarray[j].NAME;
      console.log(tmp);
      myarray[j].NAME = [];
      myarray[j].NAME.push(tmp);
      myarray[j].NAME.push(myarray[i].NAME);
      myarray[i] = {};
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array reduce into an object and return the array of values. Reduce into an object using the `myId` property as the key to group by. Shallow copy any existing state and and `name` array, appending the new `name` value from the current element.

```
Object.values(
  input.reduce(
    (acc, { id, myId, name }) => ({
      ...acc,
      [myId]: {
        ...(acc[myId] || { id, myId }),
        name: [...(acc[myId]?.name || []), name]
      }
    }),
    {}
  )
```

```js
const input = [
  { id: 1, myId: "100", name: "amey" },
  { id: 2, myId: "100", name: "anuj" },
  { id: 3, myId: "101", name: "suraj" },
  { id: 4, myId: "101", name: "suraj h" }
];

const res = Object.values(
  input.reduce(
    (acc, { id, myId, name }) => ({
      ...acc,
      [myId]: {
        ...(acc[myId] || { id, myId }),
        name: [...(acc[myId]?.name || []), name]
      }
    }),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const arr1 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "myId": "100",
  "name": "amey"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "myId": "100",
  "name": "anuj"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "myId": "101",
  "name": "suraj"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "myId": "101",
  "name": "suraj h"
}]

const reduced = arr1.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // 1. check if the 'acc' array already contains an item with the same 'myId' attribute
  const itemIndex = acc.findIndex(it => it.myId === item.myId);
  
  // 2. if there isn't any, push into the 'acc' array a copy of the item,
  //    with the 'name' property converted into an array of strings
  //    otherwise simply push the 'name' into the already existing item
  if (itemIndex === -1) {
    acc.push({
      ...item,
      name: [item.name]
    });
  } else {
    acc[itemIndex].name.push(item.name)
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

// test
console.log(reduced);
```